# magento 2 error message for wrong login?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

when a customer enters the wrong password my site just refreshes the login page without any error message. Is there a way to redirect and/or display an error messaging saying something like the wrong password was entered? 
thanks!

Comment: Firstly confirm you whole frontend messaging system is broken or not?

Comment: @Sohel Rana hi, ok how do I do that; I guess it is since there are no error messages.